# Vite build error (RollupError: Identifier '__vitePreload' has already been declared)

Tags: npm, vite, lit

In a project written with lit element and bundled by vite, I tried importing an external css package in `my-element.ts` which is lit element's starter file and it runs no problem. But when I run `npm run build`, I get this error:

```
error during build:
RollupError: Identifier '__vitePreload' has already been declared
```